i want to make use of SideEffect to pass an int to my viewModel function viewModel.addPrice(). But my composables don't render correctly if i use it
I have created a data class called FoodItemState
data class FoodItemState(
val id: Int,
@DrawableRes val img: Int,
val foodName: String,
val price: Int,
val availability: String,
val amount: Int?,
val options: MutableList<OptionState>?
)

And in this data class is a parameter called options
val options: MutableList<OptionState>?

This options is a mutable list of option state, OptionState is another data class i created
data class OptionState(
val id: Int,
val name: String,
val price: Int,
val amount: Int?,
val upperLimit: Int?,
val lowerLimit: Int?,
val mergeGroup: Int? = null,
val mergeId: Int? = null
)

It contains an id, name, price of option (.e.g. let's say the option the user want to select is chicken, chicken would be the name and price will show the price that chicken cost). Amount is the amount of chicken you want in your order, but its nullable because for some option like soup, you can't really say you want 2 soup, you just select what type of soup you want.
Upperlimit is used for options like chicken that can have an amount. It states the maximum amount of chicken that the user can select in one food order. Lower limit is the lowest amount of chicken that the user can choose, it's mostly 1. But for options like soup that don't have amount, upper limit and lower limit will be null.
So in my Reserving screen composable, a FoodItemState is passed as the data. and if the food item is one with options, then the options in the food item is passed to a composable i call OptionsSection.
(Let me elaborate further on what i just said. There are some Food items that don't consist of options that you can choose alongside the food. Example of one is hotdog, in my app, if you order a hotdog you won't be given the option to add any additional things to the hotdog. But lets say you order rice, you can choose if you want chicken or fish -.i.e. food with options.)
In the demonstration, we'll use a Food Item that has options because the main issue i have is with the option section.
    @Composable
fun OptionsSection(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: PriceViewModel,
    data: FoodItemState
) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        NotMergedOptions(
            viewModel = viewModel,
            data = data
        )
        MergedOptions(
            viewModel = viewModel,
            data = data
        )
    }
}

The OptionSection composable contains a parameter called data of type FoodItemState.
Then there's a column which have two other composables inside it.
NotMergedOptions() and MergedOptions().
MergedOptions() composable is a composable i created to contain multiple options into a single drop down menu. I did this because there are some options that i want to combine into one drop down menu (Things like soup, i don't want every type of soup to just be showing in their individual composable in the column, i want similar options to be combined, then you can select which one you want with the drop down menu.) So how i achieved this, was by introducing the mergedGroup parameter in the FoodItemState data class. mergeGroup is null by default, then if i know that this particular option is one that i want to combine like soups. Then i'll give them a mergeGroup number, starting from 0. Options with the same mergeGroup number are going to be put into the same drop down menu.
FoodItemState(
    id = 1,
    img = R.drawable.eba_and_soup,
    foodName = "Eba and soup",
    price = 2500,
    availability = "Available",
    amount = null,
    options = mutableListOf(
        OptionState(
            id = 0,
            name = "Egusi soup",
            price = 400,
            amount = null,
            upperLimit = null,
            lowerLimit = null,
            mergeGroup = 0,
            mergeId = 0
        ),
        OptionState(
            id = 1,
            name = "Banga soup",
            price = 400,
            amount = null,
            upperLimit = null,
            lowerLimit = null,
            mergeGroup = 0,
            mergeId = 1
        ),
        OptionState(
            id = 2,
            name = "Vegetable soup",
            price = 600,
            amount = null,
            upperLimit = null,
            lowerLimit = null,
            mergeGroup = 0,
            mergeId = 2
        ),
        OptionState(
            id = 3,
            name = "Eba",
            price = 300,
            amount = 1,
            upperLimit = 5,
            lowerLimit = 1,
            mergeGroup = 1,
            mergeId = 0
        ),
        OptionState(
            id = 4,
            name = "Fufu",
            price = 300,
            amount = 1,
            upperLimit = 5,
            lowerLimit = 1,
            mergeGroup = 1,
            mergeId = 1
        ),
        OptionState(
            id = 5,
            name = "Turkey",
            price = 1600,
            amount = 1,
            upperLimit = 2,
            lowerLimit = 1,
            mergeGroup = 2,
            mergeId = 0
        ),
        OptionState(
            id = 6,
            name = "Chicken",
            price = 1400,
            amount = 1,
            upperLimit = 2,
            lowerLimit = 1,
            mergeGroup = 2,
            mergeId = 1
        ),
        OptionState(
            id = 7,
            name = "Goat meat",
            price = 1500,
            amount = 1,
            upperLimit = 2,
            lowerLimit = 1,
            mergeGroup = 2,
            mergeId = 2
        ),
        OptionState(
            id = 8,
            name = "Kpomo",
            price = 500,
            amount = 1,
            upperLimit = 3,
            lowerLimit = 1,
            mergeGroup = 2,
            mergeId = 3
        ),
        OptionState(
            id = 9,
            name = "Fish",
            price = 900,
            amount = 1,
            upperLimit = 2,
            lowerLimit = 1,
            mergeGroup = 2,
            mergeId = 4
        )
    )
)

Drop down menu/ merged options in the ui
The other composable in the column is the NotMergedOptions() composable. This one is pretty straight forward, this is for options that aren't meant to be added into a drop down menu.
But going inside the NotMergedOptions() composable, you'll see two other composables. OptionWithoutAmount() and OptionWithAmount().
    @Composable
fun OptionWithoutAmount(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: PriceViewModel,
    data: FoodItemState
) {
    val options = data.options!!
    var optionState: OptionState? = null
    for (option in options) {
        if (option.amount == null && option.mergeGroup == null) {
            optionState = option
        }
    }
    var priceView = optionState!!.price

    Row(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        Surface(text = optionState.name)
        PriceTextView(
            viewModel = viewModel,
            price = priceView
        )
    }
}

    
@Composable
fun OptionWithAmount(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: PriceViewModel,
    data: FoodItemState
) {
    val options = data.options!!
    var optionState: OptionState? = null
    for (option in options) {
        if (option.amount != null && option.mergeGroup == null) {
            optionState = option
        }
    }
    var amountView by remember { mutableIntStateOf(optionState!!.amount!!) }
    val lowerLimit = optionState!!.lowerLimit!!
    val upperLimit = optionState.upperLimit!!
    var priceView = optionState.price
    var price0 = priceView * amountView

    Row(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        Surface(text = optionState.name)
        IncrementSection(
            amount = amountView,
            onDecrementClicked = {
                if (amountView > lowerLimit) {
                    amountView--
                }
            },
            onIncrementClicked = {
                if (amountView < upperLimit) {
                    amountView++
                }
            }
        )
        PriceTextView(
            viewModel = viewModel,
            price = price0
        )
    }
}

Now when the data enters the OptionWithoutAmount composable, I use a for loop to loop through all the options in the Food item, then
val options = data.options!!
var optionState: OptionState? = null
for (option in options) {
    if (option.amount == null && option.mergeGroup == null) {
        optionState = option
    }
}

This code filters out the options in the list that have a mergeGroup number or an amount. Because this composable is for options without amount.
Then also, for the OptionWithAmount() composable, it filters out optios that hava a mergeGroup and options that have no value for amount. Because it is used to display options with amount.
val options = data.options!!
var optionState: OptionState? = null
for (option in options) {
    if (option.amount != null && option.mergeGroup == null) {
        optionState = option
    }
}

On the other side. i.e. the MergedOptions() composable, it almost similar, just that options that enter here are options with a mergeGroup number.
Then they get seperated into MergedOptionsWithoutAmount() and MergedOptionsWithAmount().
 @Composable
fun MergedOptions(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: PriceViewModel,
    data: FoodItemState
) {
    var mergeNumberCounter by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }
    var optionIndex by remember { mutableIntStateOf(-1) }
    val options: MutableList<OptionState> = data.options!!
    for (option in options) {
        optionIndex++
        if (option.mergeGroup == mergeNumberCounter && option.amount == null) {
            MergedOptionsWithoutAmount(
                data = data,
                viewModel = viewModel,
                mergeGroupNumber = mergeNumberCounter
            )
            mergeNumberCounter++
        } else {
            if (option.mergeGroup == mergeNumberCounter) {
                MergedOptionsWithAmount(
                    data = data,
                    viewModel = viewModel,
                    mergeGroupNumber = mergeNumberCounter,
                    optionIndex = optionIndex
                )
                mergeNumberCounter++
            }
        }
    }
}

Now there are some thing i'll have to explain amount the mergedOptions composable. var mergeNumberCounter by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) } this is a value i use because, in a food item, we can have multiple mergedOptions .i.e. multiple drop down menus. So...
for (option in options) {
    optionIndex++
    if (option.mergeGroup == mergeNumberCounter && option.amount == null) {
        MergedOptionsWithoutAmount(
            data = data,
            viewModel = viewModel,
            mergeGroupNumber = mergeNumberCounter
        )
        mergeNumberCounter++
    }

so, if (option.mergeGroup == mergeNumberCounter will bring out all the options that have mergeGroup number of 0, then they will be added into a single drop down menu, and after the if statement, mergeNumberCounter in increased mergeNumberCounter++. This increment will then mean the value for mergeNumberCounter is now 1, then the loop will run again and get all options with mergeGroup number == 1. Thus creating another drop down menu.
I also made it so that the price of the option is appearing dynamically in a composable i call PriceTextView().
Elaborating further.. let's say we have a drop down menu that contains Chicken, fish and egg. If you click on Fish, i want the price of fish to appear on the PriceTextView composable.
How i achieved this is by making it so that my drop down menu composable returns the index of any option in the menu that's clicked.
Then that index is used to access a list i've created of the prices. The index will change depending on which option in the drop down menu is clicked, then that index will also be used as the index of the price in the list.
var index = dropdownMenu(data = data, mergedGroupNumber = mergeGroupNumber)
    var priceView = numberList[index]
    PriceTextView(
        viewModel = viewModel,
        price = priceView
    )

 DropdownMenu(
        modifier = modifier.background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background),
        expanded = isExpanded,
        onDismissRequest = { isExpanded = false }
    ) {
        nameList.forEachIndexed { index, text ->
            DropdownMenuItem(
                modifier = modifier.background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background),
                colors = MenuItemColors(
                    textColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground,
                    leadingIconColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground,
                    trailingIconColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground,
                    disabledTextColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground,
                    disabledLeadingIconColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground,
                    disabledTrailingIconColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground
                ),
                text = {
                    Text(
                        text = text,
                        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground
                    )
                },
                onClick = {
                    selectedText = nameList[index]
                    isExpanded = false
                    mergeIndex = index
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
return mergeIndex

In the drop down menu, on click of the option, the index is returned out.
onClick = {
                    selectedText = nameList[index]
                    isExpanded = false
                    mergeIndex = index
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
return mergeIndex

Now there are some other things i'll like to address.
In some composables, you'll see things like Surface(), IncrementSection() and PriceTextView().
Example of what i mean:
    @Composable
fun OptionWithAmount(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: PriceViewModel,
    data: FoodItemState
) {
    val options = data.options!!
    var optionState: OptionState? = null
    for (option in options) {
        if (option.amount != null && option.mergeGroup == null) {
            optionState = option
        }
    }
    var amountView by remember { mutableIntStateOf(optionState!!.amount!!) }
    val lowerLimit = optionState!!.lowerLimit!!
    val upperLimit = optionState.upperLimit!!
    var priceView = optionState.price
    var price0 = priceView * amountView

    Row(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        Surface(text = optionState.name)
        IncrementSection(
            amount = amountView,
            onDecrementClicked = {
                if (amountView > lowerLimit) {
                    amountView--
                }
            },
            onIncrementClicked = {
                if (amountView < upperLimit) {
                    amountView++
                }
            }
        )
        PriceTextView(
            viewModel = viewModel,
            price = price0
        )
    }
}

Surface is just a ui where the name of the option is displayed.
    @Composable
fun Surface(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    text: String
) {
    OutlinedCard(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp),
        border = BorderStroke(width = 2.dp, color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground),
        colors = CardColors(
            containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background,
            contentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground,
            disabledContentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground,
            disabledContainerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background,
        )
    ) {
        Box(
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(125.dp)
                .height(50.dp)
                .padding(5.dp)
        ) {
            Text(
                text = text,
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodySmall
            )
        }
    }
}

IncrementSection is used to display the amount of the option. It is used for options like chicken which you can select the amount.
    @Composable
fun IncrementSection(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    amount: Int,
    onDecrementClicked: () -> Unit,
    onIncrementClicked: () -> Unit
) {
    Row(
        modifier = modifier.wrapContentWidth(),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(5.dp),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        Button(
            icon = R.drawable.ic_minus,
            onClicked = onDecrementClicked
        )
        Text(
            text = amount.toString(),
            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground
        )
        Button(
            icon = R.drawable.ic_plus,
            onClicked = onIncrementClicked
        )
    }
}

Then PriceTextView is what i use to display the price of the option.
    @Composable
fun PriceTextView(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: PriceViewModel,
    price: Int
) {
    Surface(text = "₦$price")
}

Quick recap:
List of options comes into the OptionSection. They get passed into MergedOptions composable and NotMergedOptions composable. In MergedOptions composable they get sent into either MergedOptionsWithoutAmount or MergedOptionsWithAmount, then in NotMergedOptions, they get sent into either OptionsWithoutAmount or OptionsWithAmount.
Then what will display in the screen is depending on the list of options that come in.
Some food items might not have any options that need to be in a drop down menu. In that case, only NotMergedOptions will be called. Then the options will be sent into either OptionWithoutAmount or OptionWithAmount.
I need a way to add any price that comes into PriceTextView() to a list. So that i can call the sum of the prices in the list to get the total cost of all the options the user chooses.
I tried using side effect inside the PriceTextView() composable but that led to my ui not displaying if more than one instance of a single composable gets created. (.i.e. if MergedOptionsWithAmount() gets created more than once, then the Ui will just display blank. Although the prices will actually be added to the list of prices that i created in a viewmodel.)
class PriceViewModel(): ViewModel() {
private val _prices = mutableStateListOf<Int>()
val prices: List<Int> get() = _prices

fun addPrice(price: Int) {
    _prices.add(price)
}

fun getTotalPrice(): Int = prices.sum()

}
If you're trying to recreate the issue. You can just ignore all the complex stuff like, MergedOptions() and just try passing options without mergeGroup number multiple times.
That is,
FoodItemState(
    id = 3,
    img = R.drawable.eba_and_stew,
    foodName = "Eba and stew",
    price = 2500,
    availability = "Available",
    amount = null,
    options = mutableListOf(
        OptionState(
            id = 0,
            name = "Stew",
            price = 400,
            amount = 1,
            upperLimit = 3,
            lowerLimit = 1
        ),
        OptionState(
            id = 1,
            name = "Eba",
            price = 300,
            amount = 1,
            upperLimit = 5,
            lowerLimit = 1
        ),
        OptionState(
            id = 2,
            name = "Fufu",
            price = 300,
            amount = 1,
            upperLimit = 5,
            lowerLimit = 1,
        )

Something like this. Because this will call the OptionWithAmount() composable more than once, then the error will appear if you use side effect to call viewModel.addPrice() function in the PriceTextView() composable.
Use these as your option section composable to simplify the process.
    @Composable
fun OptionsSection(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: PriceViewModel,
    data: FoodItemState
) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        NotMergedOptions(
            viewModel = viewModel,
            data = data
        )
    }
}

    @Composable
fun NotMergedOptions(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: PriceViewModel,
    data: FoodItemState
) {
    val options: MutableList<OptionState> = data.options!!
    for (option in options) {
        if (option.mergeGroup == null && option.amount == null) {
            OptionWithoutAmount(
                viewModel = viewModel,
                data = data
            )
        } else {
            if (option.mergeGroup == null) {
                OptionWithAmount(
                    viewModel = viewModel,
                    data = data
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

    @Composable
fun OptionWithAmount(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: PriceViewModel,
    data: FoodItemState
) {
    val options = data.options!!
    var optionState: OptionState? = null
    for (option in options) {
        if (option.amount != null && option.mergeGroup == null) {
            optionState = option
        }
    }
    var amountView by remember { mutableIntStateOf(optionState!!.amount!!) }
    val lowerLimit = optionState!!.lowerLimit!!
    val upperLimit = optionState.upperLimit!!
    var priceView = optionState.price
    var price0 = priceView * amountView

    Row(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        Surface(text = optionState.name)
        IncrementSection(
            amount = amountView,
            onDecrementClicked = {
                if (amountView > lowerLimit) {
                    amountView--
                }
            },
            onIncrementClicked = {
                if (amountView < upperLimit) {
                    amountView++
                }
            }
        )
        PriceTextView(
            viewModel = viewModel,
            price = price0
        )
    }
}

    @Composable
fun OptionWithoutAmount(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: PriceViewModel,
    data: FoodItemState
) {
    val options = data.options!!
    var optionState: OptionState? = null
    for (option in options) {
        if (option.amount == null && option.mergeGroup == null) {
            optionState = option
        }
    }
    var priceView = optionState!!.price

    Row(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        Surface(text = optionState.name)
        PriceTextView(
            viewModel = viewModel,
            price = priceView
        )
    }
}

Then in this case, your PriceTextView() will have a side effect inside it.
    @Composable
fun PriceTextView(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: PriceViewModel,
    price: Int
) {
    SideEffect { 
        viewModel.addPrice(price)
    }
    Surface(text = "₦$price")
}

The code for Surface and IncrementSection Composable is shown below
    @Composable
fun Surface(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    text: String
) {
    OutlinedCard(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp),
        border = BorderStroke(width = 2.dp, color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground),
        colors = CardColors(
            containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background,
            contentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground,
            disabledContentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground,
            disabledContainerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background,
        )
    ) {
        Box(
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(125.dp)
                .height(50.dp)
                .padding(5.dp)
        ) {
            Text(
                text = text,
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodySmall
            )
        }
    }
}

    
@Composable
fun IncrementSection(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    amount: Int,
    onDecrementClicked: () -> Unit,
    onIncrementClicked: () -> Unit
) {
    Row(
        modifier = modifier.wrapContentWidth(),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(5.dp),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        Button(
            icon = R.drawable.ic_minus,
            onClicked = onDecrementClicked
        )
        Text(
            text = amount.toString(),
            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground
        )
        Button(
            icon = R.drawable.ic_plus,
            onClicked = onIncrementClicked
        )
    }
}

This should help you recreate the error while avoiding the complex code found in MergedOptions.
My aim is to find a way to add the prices that enters price text view. I suspect my current approach of using side effect isn't the correct way to go. and i'd appreciate help with any other way i can achieve the result needed.
I want to make use of the sum of the prices in another composble called QuantityBottomBar()
val testPrice = viewModel.getTotalPrice()

QuantityBottomBar(
        modifier = modifier.navigationBarsPadding(),
        price = testPrice,
        itemPrice = data.price,
        upperLimit = amount,
        data = data
    )


SideEffect is executed on every recomposition. Since you cannot effectively control recompositions and they may occur as often as every frame, calling a view model method like addPrice seems to be inherently flawed. It seems especially useless when you want to store a parameter. From the question it is unclear why you even want to call SideEffect in the first place. Why not update the view model when the change actually occurs? Also, you should never pass view models to composables. Please [edit] and provide enough context so we can understand what you actually want to achieve.

I'm an extreme noob, sorry for not adding that. This is my first attempt at creating an app. What i want to achieve is to dynamically change the total price that a food order cost based on what option the user selects while he or she is making the order. (.e.g. if he selects fish instead of meat, the price of fish will enter the PriceTextView composable, i then want to send that price to the view model list where i can now call a sum function that adds the prices in the list. With the aim of getting the total price to be displayed in another seperate bottomBar composable).

Being new to the topic isn''t an issue. The problem with the question is that it contains lots of questionable code and not enough context for us to sort it out. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mre] that we can actually execute and that exhibits the problem you have so we can reproduce it.

I've updated my post sir

Hi, was the edit helpful? I'd still appreciate your help

Sorry for the late reply, but I'm afraid this didn't help. You actually added code where you instead should have replaced the code. And you should create a minimal example. There is way too much irrelevant code. Please remove all code that is not strictly necessary to reproduce the issue. Then again, there also is a lot of code missing: What are PriceViewModel, OptionState, IncrementSection, createNumberList and so on? When they are essential to demonstrate the issue please add them too. But probably they are irrelevant? Then their usage need to be removed.

Please thoroughly read how to create a [mre] again. If you have trouble with this you can create a new project and copy only the code you think is relevant to that new project. Then make it compile and verify it still exhibits the problematic behavior. Then start removing everything that can be removed without harming the reproducibility. For example, is upperLimit really necessary, or would the problem still persist if you would remove it? Please make sure to illustrate your problem as short as possible. Keep in mind: Everything you write somebody else needs to read.

Ok sir. It will be a lot of code. But I'll do it. Things like increment section was just a UI element to display and increment the int passed to it, so I thought it won't be necessary to show that. I'll replace everything tho. Thanks

No, it needs to be only the necessary code. That won't be much. You need to keep it short.

I've made the edit. Don't be overwhelmed. From the part that says Quick recap is the place you should start from but i had to explain a lot above that to give context.
